# ggmap + ggplot will not plot certain values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap

I am trying to take a spatial dataset, rotate it, and plot both of them with ggplot/ggmap. I have included the dataset, my functions used to rotate the dataset about an origin, and the method of plotting that I wish to use.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(scales)
source("DEMOFunctions.R")

PlantLAT <- 39.28682
PlantLON <- -96.1172
Emissions <- 12591532084.8523
Resolution <- 0.1

DataPoints <- read.delim("JEC-10000m2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "")
Origin_DataPoints <- ShiftToOrigin("S", DataPoints, PlantLAT, PlantLON)

Rotated_Origin_DataPoints <- RotateDispersion(Origin_DataPoints, 25)

Rotated_DataPoints <- ShiftToOrigin("U", Rotated_Origin_DataPoints, 
PlantLAT, PlantLON)

Quantiles <- quantile(DataPoints$CO2, c(0.1, 0.955))
qn01 <- rescale(c(Quantiles, range(DataPoints$CO2)))

map <- get_map(location = c(lon = -95, lat = 43), zoom = 6, maptype = 
"terrain", colo = "bw")

ggmap(map) +
  geom_raster(data = DataPoints, aes(x = LON, y = LAT, fill = CO2), 
  interpolate = TRUE) +
  geom_raster(data = Rotated_DataPoints, aes(x = LON, y = LAT, fill = CO2), 
  interpolate = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colorRampPalette(c("limegreen", "yellow", 
  "orange", "red4"))(50),
                   values = c(0, seq(qn01[1], qn01[2], length.out = 2000), 
    1), 
                   limits = c(min(DataPoints$CO2), max(DataPoints$CO2)),
                   name = "Concentration (kg/cbm)",
                   guide = FALSE) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("Longitude") +
  ylab("Latitude") +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black", face = 
  "bold", angle = -90)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 30, face = "bold")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), 
    axis.title=element_text(size=25,face="bold")) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 10, b = 
10, l = 10))) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
```

I can get "DataPoints" to plot every time but the rotated "Rotated_DataPoints" only plots sometimes; it depends on how much I rotate it. (This can be adjusted by the number included in the "RotateDispersion" function.)

I'm confused by this inconsistency. (In a previous attempt at a solution, I restricted the number of decimal places to 4 in the rotated dispersion file but that was only a minor improvement and there were still plotting inconsistencies.)

The "JEC-10000m2.txt" file can be found [here](https://github.com/rotendd/STACK-project/blob/master/Figures/JEC-10000m2.txt) and the "DEMOFunctions.R" script can be found [here](https://github.com/rotendd/STACK-project/blob/master/Figures/DEMOFunctions.R). This script contains the "ShiftToOrigin" and "RotateDispersion" functions.

Thanks in advance for any help! Sorry about the formatting of the code and sparse commenting. This code was intended as a "proof of concept" run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate the dataset, adjacent points on the x or y-axis may become so close together that `geom_raster()` (or `geom_tile()`, `geom_raster()` is just a special case) end up creating tiles with 0 width / height.

Let's illustrate with a simple example:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
orig <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:5, each = 4),
  y = rep(1:4, 5),
  z = rpois(20, lambda = 5)
)

orig <- orig %>%
  mutate(t = case_when(x == 1 & y == 1 ~ "C1",
                       x == 1 & y == 4 ~ "C2",
                       x == 5 & y == 4 ~ "C3",
                       x == 5 & y == 1 ~ "C4",
                       TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Before rotation, this is what the plot looks like (I added labels for the 4 corners so that it's easier to follow the rotation):

```
p.orig <- ggplot(orig, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z, label = t)) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 6), y = c(0, 5)) +
  theme_bw()

p.orig + geom_point(shape = 22, size = 10) + geom_text() + ggtitle("Unrotated points")

p.orig + geom_raster() + geom_text() + ggtitle("Unrotated raster")
```

[image: unrotated]

We can see that the data points are located in straight rows & columns, perpendicular to the x / y axes. The corresponding tiles created by geom_raster touch one another nicely.

Now let's rotate the dataframe slightly (I adapted the relevant code from the `RotateDispersion()` function):

```
theta = 5/100
rotated <- orig %>%
  mutate(y = x * sinpi(theta) + y * cospi(theta),
         x = x * cospi(theta) - y * sinpi(theta))

p.rot <- ggplot(rotated, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z, label = t)) +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(0, 5), y = c(0.5, 5.5)) +
  theme_bw()

p.rot + geom_point(shape = 22, size = 10) + geom_text() + ggtitle("Rotated points")
p.rot + geom_raster() + geom_text() + ggtitle("Rotated raster")
```

[image: rotated]

The plot for `geom_points()` rotated without any other difference (point size is controlled explicitly with `size = 10`), but the tiles in the `geom_raster()` plot shrunk significantly.

A closer look reveals that the size of each tile is limited by the distance between adjacent data points on each axis. (lines added using Photoshop)

[image: zoomed]

For some angles of rotation (e.g. `theta = 25/100`), `geom_tile()` will return a blank canvas since the width & height of each tile get squeezed to 0, while `geom_raster()` will throw an error.

Depending on your use case, `geom_point()` may work better than `geom_raster()` or `geom_tile()`.